# Errors Changed inside Collection Changed event does not get raised

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, inotifycollectionchanged

I have an fullproperty like that in my VM:

```
public ObservableCollection<ServiceHost> ServiceHosts
{
    get => serviceHosts;
    set
    {
        if (serviceHosts == value) { return; }
        serviceHosts = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

In my other ViewModel for my MainWindow I'm using the `CollectionChanged` event on the ServiceHosts property to get the item that was added, convert it to my expected Type and listen to `ErrorsChanged` event that is a property from that type.
This looks like that:

```
ServiceHostViewModel.ServiceHosts.CollectionChanged += ServiceHostsOnCollectionChanged;

private void ServiceHostsOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        if (e.NewItems[0] is ServiceHost newItems)
        {
            newItems.Validator = new ServiceHostValidator();
            newItems.ErrorsChanged += (o, args) => UpdateAllErrors();
            newServiceHost.ValidateAllProperties();

        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the `ErrorsChanged` event never triggers the `UpdateAllErrors` method, even when the cells show a red border, this event doesn't execute and I don't know why.
Here is a working example where I also use the `ErrorsChanged` event, but here I add the data to `ServiceHosts` from code and not the UI:

```
private void SetErrorsChangedEventToAllServiceHosts(XmlParserBase xmlParserBase)
{
    foreach (var serviceHost in xmlParserBase.GetServiceHostClients(new ServiceHostValidator()))
    {
        ServiceHostViewModel.ServiceHosts.Add(serviceHost);
        serviceHost.ErrorsChanged += (sender, args) => UpdateAllErrors();
    }
}
```

Why does the ErrorsChanged event in the `ServiceHostsOnCollectionChanged` doesn't work?
Any help is appreciate.

Update by comment:
Here is some code from my model class

```
public class ServiceHost : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public IValidator<ServiceHost> Validator;

    public ServiceHost(IValidator<ServiceHost> validator)
    {
        this.Validator = validator;
        this.Validator.ErrorsChanged += (s, e) => OnErrorsChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you raising the `ErrorsChanged` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a working solution. Like I mentioned in the comments to @mm8 I found out that this code:

```
Validator.ErrorsChanged += (s, e) => OnErrorsChanged(e);
```

which was in my constructor, never got called because by using `e.NewItems[0] is ServiceHost newServiceHost` to check my runtime type I didn't create a new instance and therefore didn't called the constructor. I tried moving that part outside the constructor and inside `ValidateAllProperties` method which works fine now.

In my case this method gets called immediately after I'm subscribing to ErrorsChanged property from MainWindow VM.

```
newServiceHost.ErrorsChanged += (o, args) => UpdateAllErrors();
```

If you have assumptions or better ideas let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately the ErrorsChanged event never triggers the UpdateAllErrors method, even when the cells show a red border, this event doesn't execute and I don't know why.

It's up to the class that implements the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface to explicitly raise the `ErrorsChanged` event

It doesn't get raised by the framework whenever the cells show a red border. The red border could for example mean that the source property could not even be set. For example, you cannot set a property of a type `T` to any other value than an instance of `T`.

Comment: Alright, you got me an idea what the problem might be. My model class `ServiceHost` is raising the `ErrorsChanged` event but in the constructor. When I compare my first code with the working code, i see that in the working example I create a new object and therefore my constructor gets called, while in the first code i just convert it to an object of that type. Might this be a problem? I will post the code that I mentioned.

Comment: *Might this be a problem?* Well, yes, if you don't raise the event, the handler will never get called.

Comment: Alright, I added some code in the question that I mentioned in the comment. If that's the problem how can I change `e.NewItems[0] is ServiceHost newServiceHost` this part of code to call the constructor and subscribe to that event? Or where else could I position the event handler?

Comment: The event should get raises whenever there is an error. I don't know why you are raising it in the constructor. If you want to update the state when an object gets created/added, why don't you simply call `UpdateAllErrors` directly instead of waiting for an event that never gets raised?

Comment: When I just call the method directly, like you mentioned, it only gets called once. But I want to call it every time when the Errors change.. I just had a look and like I thought the problem is that with this call `e.NewItems[0] is ServiceHost newServiceHost` I'm not using the constructor and therefore don't subscire to the event inside. Like I asked above is there any possibility how I can call the constructor with `e.NewItems[0]`?

Comment: I just moved my ErrorsChanged event from the constructor to a method that get's called inside the `if (e.NewItems[0] is ServiceHost newServiceHost)` block. It works fine until now. See my answer for more details. Anyway thanks for helping me out.